# Parenting clone to the workspace restricted-roblox lua

Tags: lua, roblox

I am trying to make a Roblox game where the user presses a cat and a random event happens, here in this event I wanted a part in the replicated storage to be cloned then parented to the workspace. but something is wrong and it gives me an error of "unexpected identifier when phrasing an expression"

oh by the way the only thing underlined is the "=" after the .parent

here is the code:

> Blockquote

```
--variables
local Rep_storage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local Cat = workspace["Cat button"].cat
local num_of_events = 1 --change depending on number of events

--main function
Cat.ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(function()
    if Cat.ClickDetector.Clickable.Value == true then
        local Rand_event = math.random(1,num_of_events)
        --events
        if Rand_event == 1 then
            local lava_cat = Rep_storage["event items"]["lava cat"]
            local clone = lava_cat:Clone().Parent = workspace
            
        end
    end
end)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Unexpected identifier when parsing expression" means that you have written syntactically invalid code.

On this line :

```
local clone = lava_cat:Clone().Parent = workspace
```

The issue is that you cannot set equality twice on a single line. You can initialize the `local clone` variable, or you can set the `.Parent` property. You cannot do both at the same time.

The fix is simple, just break this line into two :

```lua
local clone = lava_cat:Clone()
clone.Parent = workspace

-- or don't bother creating a variable
-- lava_cat:Clone().Parent = workspace
```

Answer (score -1):

ok so first off, you prob want to change "clone" to two lines

```
local clone = lava_cat:Clone()
clone.Parent = workspace
```

And, if that still doesn't work, add

```
clone.Archivable = true
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).